# SimpleAutoCompleteTextField edit popup

Tags: flutter

Is it possible to change the suggestion popup?
I can't find a way to change the suggestion popup: text style, etc ....
Thanks for any replies.

[popup image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RPSnW.jpg)

```
                          new Flexible(
                    child: SimpleAutoCompleteTextField(
                      key: key,
                      controller: controllerList,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                        contentPadding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
                        labelText: 'prodotto da acquistare',
                        hintText: 'inserisci',  
                        icon: Icon(Icons.local_grocery_store),
                        //isDense: true,
                      ),
                      suggestions: suggestions,
                      textChanged: (text) => currentText = text,
                      // clearOnSubmit: false,
                      clearOnSubmit: true,
                      textSubmitted: (text) => setState(() {
                        if (text != "") {
                          name = text;
                          validate();
                        }
                      }),
                    ),
                  ),
```

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of `SimpleAutoCompleteTextField`, use `AutoCompleteTextField` which has an `itemBuilder` callback that returns a widget. This callback is used to build each item that is going to be displayed as a suggestion in the list. Since it returns a widget, then you may apply the styles you want in the suggestion list per your need.
I wrote about this in detail here and how you can change the display of the suggestions displayed: https://medium.com/flutter-community/implementing-auto-complete-search-list-a8dd192bd5f6

Hope this helps.